# prior predictive distribution negative binomial in R

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, bayes

I have a prior distribution Gamma(1.71,1.05) from a Poisson(2.2), and I know that the prior predictive distribution will be a Negative-Binomial of Gamma parameters i.e. Neg-bin(1.71,1.05).
I would want to plot the three functions with R but I don't know how to graph the Negative-Binomial.
I've done:

Gamma

```
x <- seq(0, 100, length=200)
Gamma <- dgamma(x, shape=1.71, scale=1.05) 
plot(x, Gamma, type="l",ylim=c(0,0.5), xlim=c(0,40))
```

Poisson

```
plot (x, dpois(x, 2.2),type = "h")
```

Negative-Binomial

```
barplot(table(rnbinom(10000,1.71,1.05))/10000)
```

Comment: Why would you not get probabilities for the negative binomial using `dnbinom`?

Comment: @Glen_b So $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of Gamma distribution what are in `dnbinom(x, y, p)` ? Thanks

Comment: Wikipedia [Negative binomial distribution: Gamma-Poisson mixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma.E2.80.93Poisson_mixture)